# How to include Javascript-generated text into HTML div and define font, size etc?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a parody page about a certain British politician, using Javascript to automatically generate his policies.

I have got the Javascript generating the text working just fine at my site. However, I'm not quite managing to get the Javascript output to display properly within the "speech balloon" on the test.html page (sorry if it's against the rules to post the URLs, I just thought it would be easier to illustrate what I'm saying by pointing people to the actual page).

A few questions here:

1) I'm using an iframe to try and put the policies into the speech balloon. First off, I'm not sure how to make the div so that it will always be in the correct position relative to the picture. Any clues on the CSS code I need? Or would I be better off abandoning relative positioning altogether and use absolute values?

2) Even more importantly, how do I get the policy text to word wrap within the balloon? It only needs to word wrap within a box in the balloon, I don't need anything fancy like following the contours of the balloon.

3) How do I give the text attributes like font, size etc?

I have searched for similar questions but I haven't found anything that I can apply directly to my particular project.

Thanking you in advance for your help, this looks like an amazingly useful site here.

UPDATE: OK guys, I'm obviously out of my depth here, so some advice on simpler ways of achieving this if possible would be appreciated.

The code of the text generator can be seen by viewing the source code of the policies.html link.

What I'm trying to do is get this generated text to appear on the test.html page. But I can only get it to show in plain text, without any formatting, and it isn't wrapping within the text box either.

Comment: Posting some code that shows what you're doing would be helpful for review.  That would allow answers to give specific code that would help you.

Comment: @Jesse, I tried posting some of the text generator code in this comment but there wasn't enough room to post the whole of the script. I'll try posting it further down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, and you will probably need to cut your image into pieces to fit the text inside.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRandomText()
    {
        var verbs=['Butcher','Punish','Impoverish','Annihilate','Dispossess','Humiliate','Denounce','Vilify','Torture','Execute','Shaft'];
        var victims=['single mothers','young people','the disabled','benefit scroungers','council tenants','council estate riff-raff','human rights lawyers','do-gooders','judges who say I am wrong','the poor'];
        var outcomes=['until they vote Tory','with a spoon','with a cattle prod','with a Taser','with a spoon','during a zombie apocalypse'];
        var endings=[' and then cut their benefits.',', then let Dementors suck out their lifeforce.',', then give bankers another bailout.',' and then make them work for nothing.','. I will pass emergency regulations to make it legal.',' and send their relatives to the workhouse.',', then let them eat cake.'];

        for(x=0;x<Math.round(Math.random()*10);x++){
            var _JuNk=Math.random();
        }

        return verbs[Math.round(Math.random()*(verbs.length-1))]+' '+victims[Math.round(Math.random()*(victims.length-1))]+' '+outcomes[Math.round(Math.random()*(outcomes.length-1))]+endings[Math.round(Math.random()*(endings.length-1))]+'\n';
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Refresh").click(function () {
            var randomText = getRandomText();
            $("#Result").html(randomText);
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
                non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <button id="Refresh">More...</button>
            <div class="picture">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Top Left</td>
                        <td>Top Center</td>
                        <td>Rop RIght</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Middle Left</td>
                        <td><div id="Result">Balloon Content</div></td>
                        <td>Middle Right</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bottom Left</td>
                        <td>Bottom Center</td>
                        <td>Bottom Right</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end .content -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .container -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I'm not sure where in the HTML those snippets of code should go though.

Comment: The JS should go in the script .. read more about jQuery here http://jquery.com/ and the HTML should go in your main html where you have the balloon image.. you will probably need to cut the image to pieces so you could place a div inside the balloon.. you can use a table to rearrange the pieces

Comment: Thanks, will take a closer look at that later. It's 6.40am where I am, I'll try to look at it with fresher eyes later.

Comment: Thanks, but having taken a look at that link, it seems I would have to learn jQuery from scratch and I feel somewhat out of my depth doing that. I thought it would have been a relatively simple matter to do what I wanted to do but this is all sailing over my head, sorry. :(

Comment: Firs: learning jQuery is a must for any new web developer. Second: It is relatively simple. Third: Stop being afraid and see how simple it is to accomplish what you nee, i have posted the full code.

Comment: Thanks Mortalus. I actually went ahead and did a much simpler version on the site's index page. I'll certainly take a look at your code and see how I can improve the page though.

Answer (score 0):

This may not pertain to your specific question, but this is what you would do if you wanted to use PHP in an HTML Document.
First you have your PHP script (in your case its Javascript)
Then inside your HTML Document you would use something like

```
    <!--#include virtual="../quote.js" -->
```

Comment: this is Apache-specific and not always enabled by default

Comment: @eevee Well, if he is hosting this on a server computer, it would make sense to have Apache enabled, correct? I mean, not to start an argument, but its one of the simplest things you can do, security wise. Am I wrong? (please correct me, I'm new to web development)

Comment: not all servers run Apache, and this _particular feature_ is not always enabled even when you're using Apache.  also the question had nothing to do with PHP, and even if it did, this is the wrong way to run either PHP or JavaScript.